# Access resources from a Javascript file using PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, primefaces

I am including a JS file in my primefaces page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/js/Config.js"></script>
```

The import works dandy, but the problem is I cannot access any of my resources inside the JS file. I'm attempting to access an image file to use for a background image in some JS generated html. I have tried using a relative path

```
... style="background-image:url('../images/icon_printer.png')" ...
```

and using the resource structure like in a CSS file

```
... style="background-image:url('#{resource['images:icon_printer.png']}')" ...
```

I am having no luck at all. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out one way to do this.

I used Firefox's Firebug extension and looked at the full path generated by the CSS resource call - `#{resource['images:icon_printer.png']}`.

If I pass in the base context path as the variable `resourcePath` to the function in my external Javascript file, then I can utilize the resource path from Firebug to access the images.

```
... style="background-image:url(\""+resourcePath+"/javax.faces.resource/images/icon_printer.png.jsf\")" ...
```

It requires the "javax.faces.resource" after the context and then the ".jsf" following the file extension to work.

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works. If anyone has a better way, then please let me know. I'm still open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have idea about how to deal with inline style in primefaces.

But this is something i did yesterday for importing custom theme.css and i made following changes to the images present in images folder of primefaces-mytheme folder.

```
background: #ffffff url("#{resource['primefaces-mytheme:images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png']}") 50% 50% repeat-x;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The EL expression doesn't work in included Javascript files. It works fine in CSS. I found a solution that works and posted it as an answer. Thanks for the effort though!